# Extremizing product over the standard simplex

Tags: optimization

I just stumbled across the following optimization problem with boundary conditions:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{extremize} & \prod_i x_i\\ \text{subject to} & \sum_i x_i = 1\\ & x_i > 0\end{array}$$

How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the strict positivity constraints $x_i>0$ are slack, because the point $1/N$ satisfies the constraints and gives a strictly positive value of the objective, while if any $x_i = 0$, the objective takes the value zero. So ignore those constraints.

Then, any strictly increasing transformation of a function has the same set of optimizers, so that if we take $\log()$ of the objective to get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \log(x_i)
$$
instead of the product things will be easier.

Now, substitute your constraint into your objective, as $x_1 = 1 - \sum_{i =2}^N x_i$ to get
$$
\max_{x_2,...,x_N} \log\left(1 - \sum_{i=2}^N x_i \right) + \sum_{i=2}^N \log(x_i).
$$
You could use a Lagrangian, but this gives the right answer without the extra work.

Now maximize with respect to each variable $x_k$, getting an FONC
$$
-\dfrac{1}{1-\sum_{i=2}^N x_i} + \dfrac{1}{x_k} = 0.
$$
Re-arrange a bit to get, for each $x_k$,
$$
x_k = 1-\sum_{i=2, i \neq k}^N x_i - x_k,
$$
or
$$
2x_k = 1-\sum_{i=2, i \neq k}^N x_i.
$$
Take some other variable $x_j \neq x_i$, and rewrite the above conditions as
$$
2x_k = 1-\sum_{i=2, i \neq k,j}^N x_i - x_j.
$$
$$
2x_j = 1-\sum_{i=2, i \neq k, j}^N x_i - x_k.
$$
and subtract to get
$$
2x_k - 2x_j = - x_j + x_k
$$
or
$$
x_k = x_j
$$
at the optimum. So all the $x_i$'s have the same value at the optimum.

Now return to the FONC
$$
2x^* = 1-\sum_{i=2, i \neq k}^N x^* \rightarrow 2x^* = 1-(N-2) x^*
$$ 
and solve to get 
$$
x^* = \dfrac{1}{N}
$$
for each $i$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try using AM-GM rule i.e. $AM \geq GM$
$$\
\left(\prod_i x_i\right)^{1/n} \leq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{n}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at a related lifted problem for the matrix $X$:

$\max_X \log\det(X)$ such that $\text{tr}(X)=1$, $X_{ii} > 0$, and $X_{ij}=0$.

Log of determinant is concave for symmetric positive definite matrices, and these constraints describe a subset of SPD matrices.

Another way to look at it is just think about the case where $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$. The constraints say that the point is in the positive orthant on the line $y = 1-x$. So the sup is $1/2$ and the inf is $0$. So I think in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the sup will be $1/n$ and the inf will be $0$.